Fix tikz shadings to page
For a beamer presentation, I want to style various elements (head, foot, colorboxes...) with shadings. However, I want the shading to be fixed to the page, and the element to show the matching portion of that. The following demonstrates what I want (no worries, the design is not what I actually want to use):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \clip ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \shade[inner color=red, outer color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \hspace*{1ex}
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else{%
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\strut\insertframesubtitle\strut\par
    }\fi
}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \clip ([yshift=2cm]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \shade[inner color=red, outer color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \strut\usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip1.4pt%
}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]%

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

For colorboxes, this approach becomes quite tedious. Is there a better alternative than this \clip-\shade-pair?
